# Delete inactive git branches older than

Tags: git, branch

I have multiple repositories with a lots of old branches that were never deleted.

Is there a way to search all branches that were not updated for a specified amount of time ?

I also want to add in that search if possible, branches that doesn't have commits ahead of master, to make sure nothing important is deleted.

At that point, I don't care if they were merged or not,

Answer (score 2):

You can do what ever you wish.

Here is a sample script which will print out all the branches with their last commit date (should be on a single line)

```
for ref in $(git branch); 
    do git log -n1 $ref 
    --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%an%Creset %C(yellow)%d%Creset %C(bold blue)%cr%Creset%n" ; 
done | cat | sort -n -k1,1
```

It will print out all branches in a cool way so you can echo the $ref to file and delete them

[image]